# Is my RelayCommand not executing because of the WeakReference?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm having an issue with MVVM's RelayCommand when using async methods.

Let's say I connect to a server to get a list of items using the await keyword. After I get the result I do a Linq query to filter just the ones I want to display at the moment. After that I create ViewModel of Type MenuContextItem which has Children of the same type. MenuContextItem has a Command Property of type RelayCommand. In the view side of things I have a Menu that binds the ItemsSource property to the ParentItem (it is encapsulated with other items on a observable collection).

The items all display correctly however the items created async don't execute the command, I assume it has something to do with async and the WeakReference used in the RelayCommand but I have no idea why.

```
        var itemsSource = await Task.Run(() => GetTheItems());
        var parentItem = new MenuContextItem("Parent Item", new ObservableCollection<MenuContextItem>());

        var finalItems = itemsSource.Where((e) => SOME QUERY HERE ).ToList();
        foreach (var e in finalItems)
        {
            parentItem.Children.Add(
                new MenuContextItem(
                    e.ItemDescription,
                    new Command<object>((menu) => ItemSpecificAction(e)),
                    true
                    ));
        }
```

**Update**: After some more testing it seems that the async call is not the issue, but I have no idea what could be, I have the same code for creating other items manually and it works as expected.

Edit: Added the MenuContextItem declaration

```
public class MenuContextItem : BindableObject
{
    #region private declarations
    private string _title;
    private Uri _icon;
    private RelayCommand<object> _command;
    private bool _isActive;
    private ObservableCollection<MenuContextoItem> _children;
    private Action<object> _action;
    #endregion

    #region initialization
    public MenuContextItem(string title, Action<object> action, bool isActive)
    {
        Title = title;
        IsActive = isActive;
        _action = action;
    }

    .... A few other constructors
    #endregion

    #region properties
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            if (_title != value)
            {
                _title = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Title);
            }
        }
    }

    public Uri Icon
    {
        get { return _icon; }
        set
        {
            if (_icon != value)
            {
                _icon = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Icon);
            }
        }
    }
    public RelayCommand<object> Command
    {
        get
        {
            if (_command == null && _action != null)
                _command = new RelayCommand<object>(_action);
            return _command;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_command != value)
            {
                _command = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Command);
            }
        }
    }
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return _isActive; }
        set
        {
            if (_isActive != value)
            {
                _isActive = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsActive);
            }
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<MenuContextItem> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
        set
        {
            if (_children != value)
            {
                _children = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Children);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Example of the same code working on different circumstances:

```
var item = new MenuContextItem("Register", null, new RelayCommand<object>((item) => Register(item)));
```

**Update 2**: **IGNORE THIS, my testing was wrong** Found that if I assign a var item with the new instance of MenuContextItem it will work as expected, but if I declare the new MenuContextItem inside the ObservableCollection.Add() method it loses the command. Now I just need to know why. I really would like to figure this out.

```
var item = new MenuContextItem(
                    e.Description,
                    null,
                    new RelayCommand<object>((menu) => ItemSpecificAction(e))
                    );
parentItem.Children.Add(item);
```

Comment: So you are saying that if you replace `var itemsSource = await Task.Run(() => GetTheItems());` with `var itemsSource = GetTheItems();` that everything works correctly?

Comment: I thought that was the reason, but after some more testing it seems that's not the problem. I really don't understand why these items are doing this, I have others that are created manually that work as expected. Could this have anything to do with where the command is created?

Comment: It could be a closure capture issue, what if you copy `e` into a local variable inside your loop: `var item = e;` and then use `item` in your `Command` constructor?

Comment: That didn't do it.

What I'm doing for the moment to fix the issue is to have a Action<object> property in the ContextMenuItem View Model and lazy load the command with that action. But I would really like to understand why creating the command in the for doesn't work.

Comment: Please post the working code for comparison, and the definition of `MenuContextItem`.

Comment: Added the rest of the code.

Comment: You are using `menu` as the parameter for your `Action`, but using `e` inside that action (passing it to `ItemSpecificAction()`. Not sure if that's the problem, but it's a difference when compared to your working example which uses the `Action` parameter.

Comment: I pass e because it's specific to business logic, the menu it's only for some specific cases. I found however that declaring the item before adding it to the collection seems to fix it.

Comment: By no means an answer, but somebody else did have a similar question (unresolved), a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202408/why-weakreferences-in-relaycommand